# compile error building Android CM 10.2 rom on OSX

Tags: android, osx-yosemite, samsung-mobile, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to compile a `CM 10.2 ROM` for `Samsung note 2 on OSX` and it is giving me the following error after i enter make -j4 :

```
    No private recovery resources for TARGET_DEVICE generic
    build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:87: **********************************************************
    build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:88: * Kernel source found, but no configuration was defined  *
    build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:89: * Please add the TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG variable to your   *
    build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:90: * BoardConfig.mk file                                    *
    build/core/tasks/kernel.mk:91: **********************************************************
    Can't open build/target/board/generic/arch/arm/configs/: No such file or directory at -e line 1.
    Can't open build/target/board/generic/arch/arm/configs/: No such file or directory at -e line 1.
    target Prebuilt:  (/Volumes/android/WORKING_DIRECTORY2/out/target/product/generic/kernel)
    host C: adb <= system/core/adb/commandline.c
    host C: adb <= system/core/adb/adb_client.c
    acp: missing destination file
    make: *** [/Volumes/android/WORKING_DIRECTORY2/out/target/product/generic/kernel] Error 2
    make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

#### make failed to build some targets (33 seconds) ####
```

In the BoardConfig.mk file the following value is already set:

`TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG := cyanogenmod_n7100_defconfig`

i am a newbie and have not been able to find any posts regarding this anywhere. I have run out of possible options to resolve this, any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

P.S. Can someone tell what value can be given if I try to set 
TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL?

Comment: Progress:
There were around 14 BoradConfig.mk files, I added `TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG := cyanogenmod_n7100_defconfig` to them one by one and was able to compile a bit more of the ROM till it failed for another reason. The conclusion I am reaching now is that the original branch I was using to compile the ROM is non-functional. If you guys have an opinion on that then let me know, meanwhile i've started working on an AOSP Lollipop ROM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing a porting and I had the same problem compiling my ROM, if you have an already compiled kernel image (for example - from the stock kernel you can build your evironment using a boot.img extracted from the stock rom with /build/tools/device/mkvendor.sh) you can put it in /device/[vendor]/[codename]/kernel and set

```
TARGET_PREBUILT_KERNEL := device/[vendor]/[codename]/kernel
```

to your BoardConfig.mk (the script mkvendor.sh will generate automatically the image from boot.img).
Instead, if you want to compile even the kernel from source you have to use

```
TARGET_KERNEL_CONFIG := cyanogenmod_codename
```

Read more [here](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_integrated_kernel_building)

Comment: What is this Coincidence , Gabry3795 from Mate 7 section is answering the question that I'm trying to answer it now , and for the same phone, Really :D